Consulta para facturas pendientes de compras
Hola tengo las tablas
documentos_compras 
------------------
id.compra
fecha 
nombre_proveedor
monto_docto

pagos
----- 
id.pago
id.compra
fecha
nombre proveedor
total_pago

Las une las clave id.compra. Necesito hacer una consulta para ver qué documentos están pendientes de pago, al hacer join no me selecciona ningún documento porque si el documento está en las dos tablas significa que está pagado y yo necesito las pendientes.

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] y, al hacerlo, ganar tu primera medalla. Para poder responder apropiadamente, me queda la duda ¿Tu sistema acepta pagos parciales? Pregunto porque la tabla pago tiene el campo total_pago. Si tu sistema acepta pagos parciales, no solo los documentos que no están en la tabla de pagos debieran aparecer en el resultado, cierto?  Sino todos los documentos cuyo monto no haya sido totalmente cubierto con los pagos,  ¿O buscas solo los que no tienen ningún pago?

Si, acepta pagos parciales por lo que también deberian aparecer en el resultado las facturas pendientes parciales

Para determinar los documentos pendientes de pago y tomando en cuenta que un documento puede recibir pagos parciales y puede recibir varios pagos, necesitarías, primero, saber el valor total pagado a cada documento. Puedes obtenerlo, por ejemplo, con esta consulta:
select `id.compra`, sum(total_pago) total_pagado
  from pagos
 group by `id.compra`

Teniendo esta información, para saber el saldo, necesitaríamos hacer un outer join de la tabla de compras con este resultado, efectuar la resta del monto menos el total pagado y finalmente filtrar los que tengan un saldo mayor que cero (o quizás distinto de cero en caso que se haya operado un pago en exceso, ya dependerá de las reglas de negocio y validaciones que tengas).
A mi manera de ver, la manera más elegante de hacerlo es usando un CTE:
with
ResumenPagos as (
select `id.compra`, sum(total_pago) total_pagado
  from pagos
 group by `id.compra`
)
select c.*
       , coalesce(p.total_pagado, 0) total_pagado
       , c.monto_docto - coalesce(p.total_pagado, 0) saldo_pendiente
  from documentos_compras c
       left join ResumenPagos p on p.`id.compra` = c.`id.compra`
 where c.monto_docto - coalesce(p.total_pagado, 0) > 0

Dado que pueden haber documentos sin pago, utilizamos left join y nos valemos de la función coalesce() para tratar los posibles nulos.
Si tu versión de mysql no soporta CTE's, puedes usar una tabla derivada:
select c.*
       , coalesce(p.total_pagado, 0) total_pagado
       , c.monto_docto - coalesce(p.total_pagado, 0) saldo_pendiente
  from documentos_compras c
       left join (select `id.compra`, sum(total_pago) total_pagado
                    from pagos
                   group by `id.compra`
                 ) ResumenPagos p on p.`id.compra` = c.`id.compra`
 where c.monto_docto - coalesce(p.total_pagado, 0) > 0

La idea, como ves, es exactamente la misma, pero considero que la consulta es más difícil de leer y, por tanto, favorezco la primera sintaxis, si está disponible.
